¿Dónde tengo el error?
Hace poco inicié a practicar con clases y estoy entendiendo poco. Ahora estoy con herencia y por alguna razón no me está dejando la clase dni pasarle datos.
El error que salta me dice

"no matching function for call to 'dni::dni(string&,int&,int&,char&)'

Estuve tratando de entender primero cómo hacerle el pasaje de Persona a dni y creo que lo hice bien (al menos me dejó de tirar error ahí).
Pero ahora no me deja ingresarle datos a dni, ¿cómo es la solución?
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Persona{
public:
    Persona (int _edad, string _nombre, string _apellido){
        edad=_edad;
        nombre=_nombre;
        apellido=_apellido;
    }
    void veredad(){
        cout<<edad<<endl;
    }
    void vernombre(){
        cout<<nombre<<endl;
    }
    void verapellido(){
        cout<<apellido<<endl;
    }
protected:
    int edad;
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
};

class dni : public Persona{
public:
    dni(string _calle, int _altura, int _documento, char _genero, string nombre, string apellido, int edad) : Persona(edad,nombre,apellido){
        calle=_calle;
        altura=_altura;
        documento=_documento;
        genero=_genero;
    }
    void mostrardoc(){
    cout<<"El documento nro: "<<documento<<" .Pertenece a "<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" de "<<edad<<" años"<<endl;
    cout<<"Vive en "<<calle<<" .Altura "<<altura<<endl;
    cout<<"Es de genero "<<genero<<endl;
    }
private:
    string calle;
    int altura;
    int documento;
    char genero;
};
int main () {
    int edad;cin>>edad;
    string nombre,apellido;cin>>nombre>>apellido;
    Persona per(edad,nombre,apellido);
    string calle;cin>>calle;
    int altura,documento;cin>>altura>>documento;
    char genero;cin>>genero;
    dni dni1(calle,altura,documento,genero);
    dni1.mostrardoc();
    return 0;
}


Hay muchos errores. De partida, el constructor de dni recibe 7 parámetros y tú sólo le pasas cuatro,

@CandidMoe yo tenia entendido que eso se pasaban automaticamente cuando se ponia class dni : public persona y al lado del constructor los datos que queria, como seria entonces?

Además un DNI no hereda de la clase Persona. Es un entidad independiente. Una persona tiene un nombre y puede tener un DNI.

Herencia es que tu clase va a contener todo lo que tenga la otra clase y sea publico.. pero el constructor es de la clase..

El problema como mencionaron en los comentarios es que dni tiene más parámetros que los argumentos que le pasas:
dni(string _calle, int _altura, int _documento, char _genero, string nombre, string apellido, int edad) : Persona(edad,nombre,apellido){
    calle=_calle;
    altura=_altura;
    documento=_documento;
    genero=_genero;
}

La clase dni tiene 7 parámetros pero solo le pasas 4:
dni dni1(calle,altura,documento,genero);

No hay razón para pensar que los otros 3 parámetros se pasan automáticamente. Si así lo fuera, cómo sabría de dónde tiene que obtener esa información? Simplemente no puede saberlo.
per y dni1 son 2 objetos diferentes.
Es mejor pensar que dni y persona solo tienen atributos en común. Entonces dejas de lado la herencia, repites solo los atributos de interés y creas un método en la clase Persona para obtener un dni. Por ejemplo:
dni crear_dni(int numero, string direccion, int altura) {
    // Supongamos que el constructor de dni toma esos parámetros
    return dni(numero, nombre, apellido, edad, direccion, altura);
    // Pasa los valores de nombre, apellido y edad que ya tiene
    // el objeto Persona.
}

